# Inaccessible Cash State

Tags: corda

I am running into an issue with cash states. Basically I have a node that issues itself money and is unable to access an existing state to use for payment/anything. Let’s say this state is 5 dollars, if I issue 10 more, both rpcOps and the servicehub `getCashBalances` will say that I have 15 dollars. However, any cash flows that try to use more than 10 dollars will tell me I don’t have sufficient balance.

I’ve set up api endpoints for the node to even just exit the cash but it will say that I’m exiting more than I have. When I query the vault with `QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)`, I can see the state is there, and there doesn’t seem to be anything that differentiates the inaccessible state from any subsequent accessible states.

Could there be anything I’m overlooking here? The issuers are the same and the owners are hashed but should be the same, as well.

### Updated with command / code:

```
fun selfIssueTime(@QueryParam(value = "amount") amount: Long,
                  @QueryParam(value = "currency") currency: String): Response {

    // 1. Prepare issue request.
    val issueAmount = Amount(amount.toLong() * 100, Currency.getInstance(currency))
    val notary = rpcOps.notaryIdentities().firstOrNull() ?: throw IllegalStateException("Could not find a notary.")
    val issueRef = OpaqueBytes.of(0)
    val issueRequest = CashIssueFlow.IssueRequest(issueAmount, issueRef, notary)
    val self = myIdentity

    // 2. Start flow and wait for response.
    val (status, message) = try {
        val flowHandle = rpcOps.startFlowDynamic(
                CashIssueFlow::class.java,
                issueRequest
        )

        flowHandle.use { it.returnValue.getOrThrow() }
        CREATED to "$issueAmount issued to $self."
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        BAD_REQUEST to e.message
    }

    // 3. Return the response.
    return Response.status(status).entity(message).build()
}
```

Comment: Can you post the command/code you are using to issue the cash?

Comment: Sure- just updated original with code @Joel

Comment: Did some more digging and found that the `transaction_id` associated with this state had a `lock_id` set in the `vault_states` table in h2. i'm able to manually update this and set the lock_id to null, but I'm not sure why it was getting locked in the first place.

Comment: After unlocking it, the cash can be exited but it still throws an error when I try to use it to issue cash to another node.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is fixed via the later version of Corda finance jars. We have developed a couple more CorDapps samples using the `currency`  class, and we did not run into any issue. For example: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Tokens/dollartohousetoken/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/dollartohousetoken/flows/FiatCurrencyIssueFlow.java#L39

Further more, with the release of the Corda TokenSDk, Currency on Corda has actually a new way to get issue, transfer and redeem. This is done by:

```
        /* Create an instance of the fiat currency token */
        TokenType token = FiatCurrency.Companion.getInstance(currency);

        /* Create an instance of IssuedTokenType for the fiat currency */
        IssuedTokenType issuedTokenType = new IssuedTokenType(getOurIdentity(), token);

        /* Create an instance of FungibleToken for the fiat currency to be issued */
        FungibleToken fungibleToken = new FungibleToken(new Amount<>(amount, issuedTokenType), recipient, null);

        /* Issue the required amount of the token to the recipient */
        return subFlow(new IssueTokens(ImmutableList.of(fungibleToken), ImmutableList.of(recipient)));
```